# Discord Python Rewrite - Account Generator

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I Want to make a discord account generator using python and json, i can make it gen but i cant make it delete the account after genned, please help.

The code:

```
@client.command()
async def gentest(ctx):
    
    genembed = discord.Embed(
        title="Minecraft NFA",
        colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

    with open('alts.json', 'r') as f:
        alts = json.load(f)

    genembed.add_field(name="Account:", value=random.choice(alts), inline=False)

    with open('alts.json', 'w') as f:
        alts = alts.pop(alts)

    await ctx.author.send(embed=genembed)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Please check your DMs!")
```

but when i tried to gen (with the alts.pop) it sends this error:

> Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be
> interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alts is just the list of alts, it's not an index of the list (integer) for this you would have to do something like:

```py
@client.command()
async def gentest(ctx):
    
    genembed = discord.Embed(
        title="Minecraft NFA",
        colour=discord.Color.green()
        )

    with open('alts.json', 'r') as f:
        alts = json.load(f)
    
    choice = random.choice(alts)
    genembed.add_field(name="Account:", value=choice, inline=False)

    with open('alts.json', 'w') as f:
        del alts[alts.index(choice)]
        f.write(json.dumps(alts, indent=4))

    await ctx.author.send(embed=genembed)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Please check your DMs!")
```

Comment: i tried your code and after it genned, it deletes the entire list.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, you're popping one index from the same json file. Are you sure you had more in the file prior to testing?

Comment: Ahh I see, I don't use json files too often so I made the mistake of not using f, please try now and let me know how it goes!

Comment: oh, and i use [] before the alts on the .json file

Comment: and it got this error **Command raised an exception: AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'pop'**

Comment: So it's a list of dicts?

Comment: My apologies for the issues, I'm tired haha. Had to load the json, I'm not sure what your comment above meant, but give this a shot.

Comment: Sorry for the late response i just woke up from bed. Ill try that code.

Comment: got this error **Command raised an exception: UnsupportedOperation: not readable**

Comment: Add a + after the w for write/read, again my apologies.

Comment: The code now should work, after refreshing myself with some of my old json code. So sorry for the troubles! Let me know of any issues

Comment: it deletes the list and it shows a error
**Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**

Comment: I have edited it to use json.dumps but I don't recall that being needed, maybe because we're loading it via the json module. Let me know if that fixes it

Comment: it raised a error from
***with open('alts.json', 'w+') as f:
    --->alts = json.load(f)**

Comment: I just had time to sit down and edited my response to reflect what works in my testing, using del instead of pop and writing the dumps to it. Let me know what happens for you :)

Comment: No problem, sorry again for all the troubles! If I was at my PC I would have tested before I answered haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the JSON file. I made it so that the user id the the key and the value is a number 0. You can easily edit that.

This might not be what you wanted but making it like this is better in my opinion. Which is make an account for the user instead of using a set number of accounts.

```py
@bot.command()
async def gentest(ctx):
    genembed = discord.Embed(
        title="Minecraft NFA",
        colour=discord.Color.green()
    )

    with open('accounts.json', 'r') as f:
        accounts = json.load(f)

    genembed.add_field(
        name="Account:", value='Created Successfully', inline=False)

    accounts[ctx.author.id] = 0  # key is the id of the user and value is zero

    with open('accounts.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(accounts, f)

    await ctx.author.send(embed=genembed)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Please check your DMs!")
```